# How do I create a new column to identify close proximity in a time field using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas dataframe format read into a CSV under variable "mydataframe" (that is sorted by RegisterTime):

```
Name, RegistrationID, RegisterTime
Jordan, 1, 2017-08-01T00:00:05
Jordan, 2, 2017-08-01T00:00:08
Jordan, 3, 2017-08-01T00:00:10
Sarah, 4, 2017-08-01T00:00:15
Jordan, 42, 2017-08-01T00:00:16 
Sarah, 54, 2017-08-01T00:00:20
Jordan, 53, 2017-08-01T00:00:30
Jordan, 55, 2017-08-01T00:00:32
```

The dtypes for my 'RegisterTime' is 'object', and when printed shows something like this `'2017-08-01T00:00:15'`.

I want to be able to 'group' similar actions performed by users in on sitting within 10 seconds of each action into a single group.
I want to make it so that I am able to assign a new column for 'ActionGroup' that is assigned with an incremental value based on this.

Sample output dataframe:

```
Name, RegistrationID, RegisterTime, ActionGroup
Jordan, 1, 2017-08-01T00:00:05, 1
Jordan, 2, 2017-08-01T00:00:08, 1
Jordan, 3, 2017-08-01T00:00:10, 1
Sarah, 4, 2017-08-01T00:00:15, 2
Jordan, 42, 2017-08-01T00:00:16, 1 
Sarah, 54, 2017-08-01T00:00:20, 2
Jordan, 53, 2017-08-01T00:00:30, 3
Jordan, 55, 2017-08-01T00:00:32, 3
```

What is the best way to go about this (adding the ActionGroup column for the dataframe)?

Comment: Why is last line for `Jordan`'s `RegisterTime`  16 in expected output but 5 in sample input?

Comment: @Chris Because :16 is within 10 seconds of Jordan's last register time of :10. Jordan's 2nd to last time is :30, which is greater than 10 seconds of :16, which is why it got assigned 3. Both of Sarah's remains as 2 because both times are within 10 seconds of each other.

Comment: @Rolando  No he's asking why in sample input it's Jordan, 42, 2017-08-01T00:00:05 and in the sample output, it's Jordan, 42, 2017-08-01T00:00:16, 1 why are the timestamps different?

Comment: Typo. Fixed. Only difference is the addition of the ActionGroup column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the clearest way, but works:

```
import pandas as pd

df['RegisterTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RegisterTime'])
s = df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x['RegisterTime'].diff().dt.seconds.fillna(0).gt(10).cumsum().astype(str) + x['Name'])
df['ActionGroup'] = df.groupby(s.droplevel(0)).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name  RegistrationID        RegisterTime  ActionGroup
0  Jordan               1 2017-08-01 00:00:05            1
1  Jordan               2 2017-08-01 00:00:08            1
2  Jordan               3 2017-08-01 00:00:10            1
3   Sarah               4 2017-08-01 00:00:15            2
4  Jordan              42 2017-08-01 00:00:16            1
5   Sarah              54 2017-08-01 00:00:20            2
6  Jordan              53 2017-08-01 00:00:30            3
7  Jordan              55 2017-08-01 00:00:32            3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight rewrite of the answer by Chris, making use of a "global" counter.

```
from itertools import count

ctr = count(1)

df['ActionGroup'] = df.groupby('Name').RegisterTime.transform(
    # Processing each Name.
    # True if row starts an ActionGroup.
    lambda x: x.diff().dt.seconds.fillna(close + 1).gt(close)
        # New Action ID if row starts an Action Group.
        .apply(lambda b: next(ctr) if b else 0)
        # forwards fill replacing zeros with 
        # previous non-zero ActionGroup ID
        .replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
    )
```

In the end, this calls a pure Python function for each row, so one should not expect great performance. If speed is an issue, one could define a global counter using `numba.jitclass` that converts boolean arrays into labelled arrays.

Comment: Could you show what you mean by a global counter? Maximized performance is ideal.

Comment: It would be helpful to know more details, e.g. size of `df`, number of unique names and an average length of an action group.

Comment: Size of df is 10,000. Size of action group could be variable length. Could be anywhere between 2 to 100.